# Blending and Depth Test

Tags: webgl, depth, alphablending

My application shows big amount of objects in orthographic projection.
Each object is combined from few sprites on the same vertex with different textures.

For simplify:

Each object has 2 sprites: filled rectangle and outline rectangle

I've have one mesh (vertices and attributes) for each sprite type - one for all the objects fills and one for all the objects outlines. Total 2 meshes.

I'm drawing my objects (Sprites) in 2 phases - The fills mesh (which contains all fills sprites), and outlines mesh (which contains all outlines sprites)

For each object sprites - (in all the meshes) - i'm giving the same z-value so it will be drawn correctly.

Using depthFunc(LEQUAL) for drawing when same z value

as shown below:

[image]

The problem is when i want to change transparency for all objects. The depth is blocking from drawing some objects so i can't see the object behind. If i'm disabling the depth test suddenly all the outlines will jump to the front (looks much worse in the real application when the object is combined with much more than 2 sprites).

Sorting the objects will not work here because i'm drawing each mesh (fills and outlines) one after each other.

Is there any trick to do to make it happened ?

Comment: *Sorting the objects will not work here because i'm drawing each mesh (fills and outlines) one after each other*. Um, so stop doing that and sort? Why do you have to do it that way? Why can't you draw fill for sorted object 1, draw outline for sorted object 1, draw fill for sorted object 2, draw outline for sorted object 2, etc...?

Comment: I can't do that because in my app the user can say "i don't want to see the fills, or the outlines", or any other mesh. In my real app it's much more complicated because there are texts, and more items. There are more reasons why i'm doing it due to options i'm providing. So adding all the object "items"(fill,outline,...) into one mesh is making it much more not efficient for me

Comment: It's not well written code, if you don't capture the OOP spirit. Each object has it's own fill and/or outline, so you should have that option. Your code design affects other (unrelated) parts of application, which is bad. Question you code, really. You already have the answer provided by gman.

Comment: so do you have better design to suggest? i'm open. you suggest to have a buffer per object ? and when i have 10000 objects, to run over those buffers and draw then every cycle ?